# What happens when a computer is plugged into another computer by USB?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I am just curious about what happens when you have a USB 2.0 cable with two male ports, and plug both the ends in two different computers (not for data transfer reason, or any other reason, just curious)?

I have read this similar question on quora, where a writer says:

[image]

[Answer](https://qr.ae/pNKKN8)

---

### My actual concern

I purchased one 4 port USB hub and one input cable for the USB hub. I want to power my HDD + USB keyboard + mouse, and charge a phone from the USB hub.

[image]

I successfully plugged that into my laptop with the power bank, and nothing happened.

But when I write data to the HDD, the power drawn by the HDD from the power bank is significant, despite connected to the laptop as well:
[image]

So I have to keep the power bank plugged in, and maybe replace the power bank with a 5v 3 AMP phone charger. My concern is can it damage my laptop (and / or laptop's USB port) in a long run?

Comment: On a side note, when a power bank and a laptop are powering a current-hungry device like your HDD, the majority of the current would be coming from the power bank. 

That is because the power bank is usually a much stronger and more stable source than a laptop's USB port.

The same goes for a phone charger, it will supply most of the power when connected in parallel with a laptop's USB port.

Comment: Respected Isaac Wingfield's answer on Quora is not correct. Practically their is no harm in connecting the USB ports of two different computers. The over current protector wouldn't be triggered in any of the sources. The only exception is when one of the sources have malfunctioned to significantly high or low voltage with low internal resistance, which rarely happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not damage your laptop as long as the power bank keeps working normally (gives approximately 5V).

Of course the voltage from the laptop and the power bank can never be exactly same, but these interfaces are safe for use with slight voltage differences (up to 5.5 V should be definitely safe). There is usually no path for any significant amount of current to flow backwards into a USB port of a computer, except when the voltage rises to unusually high values, e.g. 12V.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer! It helps a lot, but there's a question, AFAIK, the amp provided by USB 2.0 is ~500 mA, my power brick is 3 Amp.

Also, is it safe to shut the power of the laptop down when the power bank is connected? Which draws some power from my USB, although nothing seems wrong so far...

Comment: Yes it's safe. Current wouldn't go back into the USB port of your computer even when it is powered off. (As long as power bank has not malfunctioned to give higher voltage.)